# What level do I need to be to purchase Tier 3 runes?

Tags: league-of-legends

I just hit level 20 and have lots of saved IP that I was going to use to purchase the tier 3 runes. However, I can't.  All the runes in the store still say "Level 20+" in red, and double clicking on them does nothing. I've re-logged and it's just the same.

Do you need to be a higher level to actually buy the runes versus obtaining them with the rune combiner?

Comment: It could be that the store has not yet received the update about your new summoner level -- have you tried simply waiting a few hours?

Comment: But this is the internet and I want it now :(

Comment: Well, there's always J.G. Wentworth...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to be a know issue:

> Eambo:
>
> Thanks. For now the only solution is to get level 11/21 unfortunately, but Riot are aware of this and it'll hopefully be fixed next patch. Sorry for the inconvenience :-(

From http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=1090010